# Building CompassApp (jruby app) executable from source on Windows

Tags: windows, build, rubygems, jruby, compass-sass

I would like to build the executable of **CompassApp**, a GUI application that lets webdesigners compile stylesheets by using SASS and Compass without using the command line.

The source can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/handlino/CompassApp.

CompassApp is a an application developed in **Jruby**.

From the GitHub webpage of the project:

> If you want to build your own copy, you will need **JRuby** and **rawr**

I am using Windows 7 as operating system for my webdesign projects. I never built a jruby app from source. It seems on linux it's easier to install the required things, anyway i'm using Windows now.

First i cloned the GitHub repository.

Then i installed jruby.

Now i should install rawr (https://github.com/rawr/rawr)

It seems that rawr also requires **javac** and **rake**

I saw that rawr and rake are 2 ruby gems.

1. So how do i install those 2 ruby gems for jruby on **Windows**?
2. And how do i build CompassApp from source after i have everything i need?

> I would need a step by step guide from the install of the requirements
>   to the build of the application.

(i never used jruby in the past).

If someone of you develops apps in jruby i think that can help me easily.

I thank you in advance.

Comment: I am still looking for an answer. Everyone who can help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fabio Hi, we made Compass.app and Fire.app :-)

It is easy to build Compass.app on OS X or Linux. We have a (almost) step by step guide about building Fire.app on the GitHub wiki and it can be applied to Compass.app too: https://github.com/handlino/FireApp/wiki

We have never tried to build it on Windows, and do not think it can be done easily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't try yet but as you said it seems (almost) a step by step guide. A similar wiki could be added also to Compass.app on github, so others may find it more easily. I'll try to install it, anyway i also bought your app after some time trying building it from source :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do a similar thing, but in my case only package the gems in a self-contained executable jar.  the docs are not very descriptive and some are outdated.

I tried rawr but managed to get further with [warbler](https://github.com/jruby/warbler)

here's what I did:  I created a folder named jrcompass and installed compass into it:

```
c:\test\jrcompass>%JRUBY%\jruby -S gem install compass -i .
```

I installed warbler and then ran the warble command in that folder:

```
C:\test\jrcompass>c:\apps\jruby\bin\jruby -S warble
```

that created a ~20MB jar file named jrcompass.jar which is farther than I got with rawr.

now I'm trying to execute the jar with:

```
C:\test\jrcompass>java -jar jrcompass.jar
```

and I get the following error below.  I hope that this will help you make progress.  please let me know if you figure it out.

```
Gem::LoadError: Could not find compass (>= 0) amongst [rake-0.9.2.2]
to_specs at jar:file:/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/jruby1564362137331239458extract/jruby-stdlib-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/dependency.rb:247
to_spec at jar:file:/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/jruby1564362137331239458extract/jruby-stdlib-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/dependency.rb:256
   gem at jar:file:/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/jruby1564362137331239458extract/jruby-stdlib-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems.rb:1231
(root) at file:/C:/Apps/test/jrcompass/jrcompass.jar!/jrcompass/bin/compass:22
  load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1046
(root) at file:/C:/Apps/test/jrcompass/jrcompass.jar!/META-INF/main.rb:1
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
(root) at file:/C:/Apps/test/jrcompass/jrcompass.jar!/META-INF/main.rb:1
(root) at jar:file:/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/jruby1564362137331239458extract/jruby-stdlib-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
```

Comment: I'm sorry that you couldn't manage to do it either till now. Thanks for your contribution anyway. Let's see if someone can help us to solve the problems. If i find a way i'll write the answer here and let you know. @user968244